# authorization not working in swagger jersey?

Tags: jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0

This my index.html file for swagger UI.

$(function () {
      window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/hootout/rest/api-docs",
      dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
      supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'],
      onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
        log("Loaded SwaggerUI");

```
    if(typeof initOAuth == "function") {
      /*
      initOAuth({
        clientId: "your-client-id",
        realm: "your-realms",
        appName: "your-app-name"
      });
      */
    }
    $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {
      hljs.highlightBlock(e)
    });

  },
  onFailure: function(data) {
    log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
  },
  docExpansion: "none"
});

$('#input_apiKey').change(function() {
  var key = $('#input_apiKey')[0].value;
  log("key: " + key);
  if(key && key.trim() != "") {
    log("added key " + key);
    window.authorizations.add("key", new ApiKeyAuthorization("api_key", key, "query"));
  }
})
window.swaggerUi.load();
```

});

I am implementing swagger UI first time in my project. I am use this index.html file for swagger UI. My swagger UI is working properly but I am not getting authorization for api. 
Thank you...

Comment: Please explain how exactly it is "not working". Does the UI for auth not show up? Does the auth request not reach your backend? Something else? The more details, the better.

Comment: Yes, The UI for auth not show up

Comment: Which [version of Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md) are you using? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: sorry I am not able to share screenshot

Comment: I am use swagger : <swagger-version>1.3.0</swagger-version>       Thanks